Can't send request on running docker image. Error socket hang up in postman. In browser localhost didn't send any data
I locally launched docker image successfully but i can't send any request on localhost.I have errors socket hang up in postman and localhost didn't send any data.
docker file
FROM node:20-alpine

MAINTAINER Some Dev

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./backend /app

RUN npm i

CMD ["npm","start"]

app.ts and small rout that I'm trying to reach configs.PORT = 5000 configs.HOST = 0.0.0.0
app.get('/hello',async (req:Request,res:Response,next:NextFunction)=>{
   res.json("Hello")
})

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(configs.DB_URL);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");

      app.listen(+configs.PORT, configs.HOST,() =>{
          console.log(`Server listening on ${configs.PORT} and host ${configs.HOST}`);
      })

  } catch (err) {
    throw new ApiError(err.message, err.status);
  }
};

startServer();


docker build -t buxonlineappv2 .

docker run -d -p 5555:80 buxonlineappv2

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                  NAMES
6fd90778e2df   buxonlineappv2   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   51 seconds ago   Up 39 seconds   0.0.0.0:5555->80/tcp   jolly_saha



In first i added host 0.0.0.0. Tried different ports. Tried localhost:5555/hello 0.0.0.0:5555/hello http:localhost:5555/hello

since your server is listening on port 5000, you should run this command to run the container:
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 buxonlineappv2

so that 5555 port on host maps with 5000 port in container.

Your configs.PORT is set to 5000, so your app listens on port 5000.
That means that that's the port you need to map on the container side. Right now you map port 80 with
docker run -d -p 5555:80 buxonlineappv2

You should map port 5000 like this
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 buxonlineappv2

and it should work.

This command worked.
docker run -d -p 5555:80 buxonlineappv2


Since I answered your question first and @Tarique just copied it, I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as the accepted one.
